# Passing array to URL commas and apostrophe issues

Tags: php, ios, mysql

I have created my own set of PHP files that can query a MYSQL table and send back the result in XML format. This is for an iOS app I am building.

I firstly build the request in the iOS app:

```
    //create comma separated array
    NSMutableString *postString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    for (NSString *thing in list_cache) {
        [postString appendFormat:@"%@,",[thing stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }


   //pass the comma separated array to the PHP file
    if ([stories count] == 0) {
        NSString * path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/get_list.php?list=%@",postString];
```

Then, my PHP file builds it into a query:

```
  $list = $_GET['list'];
  $listEsc = mysql_real_escape_string($list); 

  $withQuotes = "'" . str_replace(array("'", ","), array("\\'", "','"), $listEsc) . "'";
  $finalString = "(".$withQuotes.")";
  //echo $finalIn;

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 
 ON table_1.someVariable = table_2.variable WHERE variableX IN $finalString;");
```

This all works perfectly. EXCEPT when an item in the array has either an apostrophe (') or a comma (,) Then I get the following error:

```
 Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near... etc
```

I have tried fixing this with: mysql_real_escape_string like other answers suggest to similar questions. But it has not done the trick!

I have tried escaping the string, replacing commas and apostrophes with % encodings etc. Nothing seems to be working, and I can imagine there must be an industry standard solution for this issue?

[edit] Sample string as posted in a comment by the OP:

```
server.com/get_list.php?list=lorum%ipsum%20-%20%27quoted%27%20from%20The%lorum%ipsum%20soundtrack,%22Ipsum%20And%20A%20Beat%22%20-%20live%20concert%20(A%name,%20another%20word,%20and%20final%20name%20word)
```

Comment: You shouldn't be escaping the comma if the value with the comma is already wrapped in quotes.

Comment: You need to make `array("\\'", "','")` to `array("\\'", "\\',\\'")`. And also don't construct query like this, use `?` and bind parameter option

Comment: Don't mess about with the string after you've escaped it with `mysql_real_escape_string()` - you run the risk of undoing it's good work, which is probably what's happening here. Do any processing before you escape, then escape the parameters and submit the query. Also, don't use `mysql_*()` for new code - it's deprecated. Use `mysqli_*()` or `PDO`. Lastly, it would be useful to see an example of what's in `$_GET['list']`

Comment: Thank you @HoboSapiens That has fixed all items with apostrophes. The only issue now is with commas! Here is an example of what a URL looks like, I have replaced the words and variables as the project is confidential:http://server.com/get_list.php?list=lorum%ipsum%20-%20'quoted'%20from%20The%lorum%ipsum%20soundtrack,%22Ipsum%20And%20A%20Beat%22%20-%20live%20concert%20(A%name,%20another%20word,%20and%20final%20name%20word),